# Hyper-V Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, hyper-v

I have been trying to use Windows Phone Emulator and it complains that `Hyper-V` isn't there. Is `Hyper-V` only available on Pro versions of Windows?

I am running Windows 8.1 and I don't see it as a feature that can be turned on/off in Windows settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/jj721676.aspx), Hyper-V client is only available on Pro and Enterprise

> Can I run virtual machines on my desktop?
>
> Windows 8 Pro and Windows 8 Enterprise include Client Hyper-V; the same is true for Windows 8.1. You can use Client Hyper-V to develop and test applications, evaluate and learn about new technologies, and so on. This is the same virtualization technology that runs on Windows Server 2012 and Windows Server 2012 R2. For more information about Client Hyper-V, see Client Hyper-V.

Comment: It also need to be a 64-bit version.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj863509%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) you need to change your BIOS settings, then manually enable it in Windows(See Enabling BIOS settings required by Hyper-V, and Enabling Hyper-V in Windows).